# Use memcached with laravel5

Tags: caching, laravel, memcached

I'm actually configuring my cache system on my website, but I'm having a problem, when I change:

```
'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'file'),
```

to:

```
'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'memcached'),
```

The framework is always using the File method. I know it because it returns this error

```
class 'Illuminate\Cache\FileStore' does not have a method 'tags'
```

But when I call the cache method like this

```
Cache::store('memcached')->tags('hello')->add('world', 'Hello World', 10);
```

It works, but if I don't specify the store shouldn't he call the default method who is assigned in the cache config?

Comment: How does your .env file look like?

Comment: alway CACHE_DRIVER=file, did he take it ? he dont take attention at the config file? why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'memcached'),
```

means use the value of the environment variable `CACHE_DRIVER`. And default back to `memcached` if it doesn't exist.

Instead you should change the value in your `.env` file:

```
CACHE_DRIVER=memcached
```

Comment: ok, thanks i was thinking its the reverse, in first look at config, if not defined go to .env file... nvm, thanks